# c++ LAPACK library not detected whereas it's installed

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake, lapack

I have installed the lapack library using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
```

In synaptic I have checked if everything was installed and it sounds good:
[image]

I would like to compile the g2o library which use liblaback but by doing cmake I have the following output:

> CMake Error at cmake_modules/FindLAPACK.cmake:247 (message):   A
>   required library with LAPACK API not found.  Please specify library
>   location. Call Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:75
>   (FIND_PACKAGE)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I'm pretty sure that It's not because the CmakeList file and all the Cmake file including for example the **FindLAPACK.cmake** (can find it [there](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/blob/master/cmake_modules/FindLAPACK.cmake)) file because I remember to have compiled it well before using another computer with Ubuntu 14.04.

So now I don't know what is the problem. I tried to uninstall, purge and then install it again but still the same issue.

I also checked the `/etc/ld.so.conf` in case and it contains

> include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf 
>    /usr/local/lib

I did then to be sure

```
sudo ldconfig -p
```

I noticed that the library is on /usr/lib
For example:

> /usr/lib/liblapack.so
>
> /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3
>
> /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf
>
> /etc/alternatives/liblapack.so /etc/alternatives/liblapack.so.3
>   /etc/alternatives/liblapack.so.3gf /usr/lib/liblapack.so
>   /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3 /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf
>   /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so
>   /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3
>   /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3.0
>   /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3
>   /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.0
>   /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/liblapack.so
>   /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/liblapack.so.3

If I take a look on the Cmake file error, I have those lines inside:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/liblapack.a(xerbla.f.o): undefined
>   reference to symbol '_gfortran_string_len_trim@@GFORTRAN_1.0'
>   //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3: error adding symbols: DSO
>   missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

But I checked and Gfortran is well installed also.

Do you have any idea ? I getting crazy about it.

Comment: What is *exact* path (including filename) to `lapack` library? Just search it on your filesystem.

Comment: The exact path, I think is /usr/lib/liblapack.so
/usr/lib/liblapack.so.3
/usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf

But normally the findLAPACK.cmake look for it in the filesystem right ?

Comment: Hmm, according to CMake file error, it seems that problem can be in `findLAPACK.cmake` module, shipped with g2o. Try to replace it with one in CMake:  https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindLAPACK.cmake. According to log, it has some bugs fixed. Of course, clean build is required after that change.